# Method invocation failed [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext] does not contain a method named 'AcquireTokenAsync

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, adal

it is not reading the values in authcontext, not sure why, can some help me out with this. using latest version of ADAL v5.2.9

PowerShell

```
           
function Get-AccessToken
{​
    $tenantID = "<id>" 
    $AuthUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID"    
    ########
    #SPN IDs.....
    #spn
    $AppId = ""
    #######
    # SPN cert thumbprints.......
    #spn
    $clientCertificate = Get-Item -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My\<cert thumb>
    $resource = "<RestApi>"
    $adal = "<path to the dll>\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adal) | Out-Null
    $authenticationContext = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext -ArgumentList $AuthUri
    $certificateCredential = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate -ArgumentList ($AppId, $clientCertificate)
    $authToken = $authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resource, $certificateCredential)
    $accessToken = $authToken.Result.AccessToken.Trim()
    $authToken.Result.AccessToken.Trim() | Clip
    Write-Host "Token length"
    Write-Host $accessToken.Length
    $accessToken
}​
#endregion
# Get access token, headers and body
$token = Get-AccessToken
```

getting following error

```
InvalidOperation: C:\Users\Ipaws-api.ps1:17
Line |
  17 |     $authToken = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resource, $certificat …
     |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext] does not
     | contain a method named 'AcquireTokenAsync'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your issue with AcquireTokenAsync but it works well.

Step1: Install `AzureAD` in PowerShell.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD -AllowClobber
Import-Module -Name AzureAD
```

Step2: Load the ADAL assembly with `Add-Type -Path`.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.2.135\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
```

Step3: Run the following commands.

```
$tenantId = "<your tenant id>"
$clientId = "<your client id>"
$key = "<your key>"

$authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/"
$AuthContext = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]$authUrl
$cred = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential $clientId,$key
$result = $AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/",$cred)
$result.Result.AccessToken
```

[image]